# SQL Query to get all clients birthdays for this month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm trying to create a query that will display all clients born this month, but I'm getting:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Here is my code.

```
SELECT 
    t.Client_id, t.Name
FROM
    (SELECT  
         Client_id,
         C_name + ' ' + C_surname AS Name,
         CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Client_id, 3, 2)) AS M,
         CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Client_id, 5, 2)) AS D,
         CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(CHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Client_id, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Client_id, 5, 2))) AS DateOfBirth
     FROM 
         tblClientInfo) T
WHERE 
    T.M <= 12 
    AND T.DateOfBirth = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

I tried to put `CONVERT(varchar, getdate())` but still getting error

This one works well for extracting birthdays for today only:

```
SELECT 
    t.Client_id, t.Name
FROM
    (SELECT  
         Client_id,
         C_name + ' ' + C_surname AS Name,
         CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Client_id, 3, 2)) AS M,
         CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Client_id, 5, 2)) AS D,
         CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(CHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Client_id, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Client_id, 5, 2))) AS DateOfBirth
     FROM 
         tblClientInfo) T
WHERE 
    T.D <= 31 
    AND T.M <= 12 
    AND T.DateOfBirth = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: The column name `Client_id` implies a numeric value and implies that it is some sort of identifier. Yet your logic treats (or converts) it as a string containing a formatted value representing a date. Something seems very wrong here.

Comment: @SMor the first 6 numbers for Client _id are birthday, e.g. 900829 mean 29 August 1990

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select *
from tblClientInfo
where  CAST(SUBSTRING(Client_id, 3, 2) AS TINYINT) = month(getdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I'm thinking:

```
select c.*
from tblClientInfo c
where month(dateofbirth) = month(getdate());
```